# UPSERT supported on postgreSQL 9.5 only, maven repository has 9.4

Tags: maven, sbt, postgresql-9.5

I need UPSERT capability which is only supported on 9.5 and up - while the last addition to the repo is for version 9.4 (feb 2016).
So what do we do?

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql

Thanks!

Comment: The maven repository contains the **JDBC** driver, not the actual database server. The driver supports whatever the backend supports

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPSERT` with the JDBC driver 9.4. You just need to upgrade you database to Postgres 9.5